# Laravel doesn't delete record via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Here is my view:

```
<a class="js-ajax-deleteConfirm btn btn-danger rounded-pill mr-2" href="/article/{{$articles->id}}" data-id="{{$articles->id}}">delete</a>
```

Here are my scripts:

```
    $('.js-ajax-deleteConfirm').click(function () {
        let deleteConfirm = confirm('are you sure?');
    
        if (deleteConfirm == true) {
            let clickEle = $(this)
            let id = clickEle.attr('id');
    
            $.ajax({
                url: '/articles/' + id,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    'id': id,
                    '_method': 'DELETE'
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::delete('/articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@delete')->name('delete');

Here is my controller:
```

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $articles = Article::findOrFail($id);
    $articles->delete();
    return redirect()->route('articles_index')->with('msg_success', 'deleted');
}
```

How can I delete article?
after I hit delete and yes button, it stays on the same page and can not delete article.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes as per below code

in route file

```
Route::delete('/articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@delete')->name('articles.delete');
```

in blade file

```
<a class="js-ajax-deleteConfirm btn btn-danger rounded-pill mr-2" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="{{ $articles->id }}" data-url="{{ route('articles.delete', ['id' => $articles->id]) }}">delete</a>
```

js code

```
$('.js-ajax-deleteConfirm').click(function () {
    if(confirm('are you sure?')){
        var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'DELETE',
            data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                'id': id,
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for telling me that!  it does not show me "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." anymore but looks like i still cant delete article

Comment: @user19279944 your href redirect to the page so please check have you add this?? `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: The above code is working. please make changes as per code and test

Comment: thank you so much and i tried it but it is still not working..

Answer (score 0):

Change the type to delete in ajax because you are using the delete route and you don't need to add method in data.

> Route::delete('/articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@delete')->name('delete');

```
$('.js-ajax-deleteConfirm').click(function () {
    let deleteConfirm = confirm('are you sure?');

    if (deleteConfirm == true) {
        let clickEle = $(this)
        let id = clickEle.attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/articles/' + id,
            type: 'DELETE',
            data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                'id': id,
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for telling me that!  it does not show me "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." anymore but looks like i still cant delete article

Comment: Change the url in ajax as, url: '{{ url("articles") }}' + '/' + id

Answer (score 0):

Modify your js code like this and make sure that your url is right.

```
$('.js-ajax-deleteConfirm').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent your page to refresh on ajax call
    let deleteConfirm = confirm('are you sure?');
    
    if (deleteConfirm == true) {
        let clickEle = $(this)
        let id = clickEle.attr('id');
    
        $.ajax({
            url: '/articles/' + id,
            type: 'DELETE', // type should be delete as per your laravel route
            data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                'id': id,
                '_method': 'DELETE'
            },
            success: function() {
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert('Failed to delete');
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

If your js code is in blade file. You can modify your url like this which will prevent you for future url errors.

```
url: "{{URL::to('/articles')}}/" + id
```

Comment: thank you so much and i tried it but it is still not working.. it shows me just "Failed to delete" after i hit the delete button

Comment: Notice the console. You will get actual error. whether it is from frontend side or backend side.

Comment: thank you. it shows me "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and "CSRF token not found"

Comment: i fixed csrf and 404 error but im not sure how i can solve 419 error